# Multi-platform library design. Best practices

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform

What are the best practices to design functions that have different platform-specific implementations?

For example, I have a function that structurally looks like this in a library module (it is exported):

```
void foo()
{
#ifdef PLATFORM_WINDOWS
  // windows-specific implementation
#elif PLATFORM_LINUX
  // linux-specific implementation
#elif PLATFORM_SOLARIS
  // solaris-specific implementation
#endif
}
```

Each section can (and does atm) contain a lot of code, which makes it difficult to read and so on.

What is the proper way to do things like this?

Comment: Separate the different implementations into specific functions, and have the calls for them in the API functions distinguished with the ifdefs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, if understood you correctly: you suggest that each implementation needs to be extracted to functions and just called while ifdef structure stays the same, right?

Comment: Best practice is to first know which language you are using and not spam tags for very different languages.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is a good approach, but I think you can get more abstraction by enabling/disabling the parts of a function as shown in the post. The reason is, that different operating systems might need completely different headers and have completely different APIs themselves. Therefore adding the `#ifdef` outside the function would lead to unnecessary code duplication.

Comment: @jan.sende Granularity of these OS-specific functionality often differs a lot, and scatterering code with trying to find and generalize the altos, is often not worth it. Depends on use cases as always.

Answer (score 4):

If the implementations are completely different, it may be a good idea to not use preprocessor conditions, but have separate .c files for each platform. Each would contain different, platform-specific implementations of the same functions declared in a shared header file. The correct file would then be selected by the build system.

For example in GLFW, there is [x11_window.c](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/x11_window.c) and [win32_window.c](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/win32_window.c), and both implement the same functions, like _glfwPlatformGetWindowSize().

Answer (score 3):

One popular way to do this in C++ is to use interfaces to abstract away implementation details.
You can use these to create platform independent code and it also really helps to deal with situations where API's become not supported anymore.

Let's say, for example, you have an engine that you want to be able to use DirectX or OpenGL your class might look something like this.

```
class IEngine 
{
   public:
   virtual void InitEngine() = 0;
};

class OpenGLEngine : public IEngine
{
   public:
   void InitEngine() override
   {
        //OpenGL specific implementation here
   }
}
```

Then when you initialize an instance of IEngine your code will be specific to whatever type of engine you created but you can reuse the same interface code regardless of the differences in implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm replying from a C++ perspective. The answer for C is going to be drastically different, and I don't feel confident in providing any recommendations for that. Some of the principles would translate well, but some would not.

I would suggest that you hide your platform-specific code behind an interface. Inside the interface, provide a static function to return a pointer to your API, but don't define it in the platform-agnostic version of your code.

Then you create different classes inheriting from that interface in separate files, that are platform specific. 
Inside the platform-specific .cpp files, you provide a definition for the static function that is declared in your interface.

I would recommend that you absolutely exclude the platform specific files from your build script for the inappropriate platforms. Failing that, you should wrap their entirety inside the appropriate ifdef clause, but it is easy to make a mistake and not very reliable.

Do note, that in such a case, the calculations performed inside the functions themselves might be performance critical - that's OK. The restriction is that this kind of functions should not be called inside a tight loop, because of the virtual function call.

If you really need to squeeze every ounce of performance, you can get rid of the interface, loose the safety and elegance provided by it, and just implement the same functions in different .h / .cpp files. This is something you can most probably do if you're writing in C - but again, I'd prefer some C expert to state their opinion on that.

A minimal example would look something like this:

> MyPlatformSpecificAPI.h

```
class MyPlatformSpecificAPI
{
    public:
        virtual ~MyPlatformSpecificAPI() = default; //Don't forget a virtual destructor 
        static MyPlatformSpecificAPI* getPlatformSpecificAPI(); //Notice, no implementation
        virtual uint8_t myPlatformSpecificFoo(uint32_t bar) = 0;


        //Because we're declaring an explicit destructor, explicitly default the 4 special member functions, check Rule of Five
        MyPlatformSpecificAPI(const MyPlatformSpecificAPI&) = default;
        MyPlatformSpecificAPI(MyPlatformSpecificAPI&&) = default;
        MyPlatformSpecificAPI& operator=(const MyPlatformSpecificAPI&) = default;
        MyPlatformSpecificAPI& operator=(MyPlatformSpecificAPI&&) = default;
};
```

> MyPlatformSpecificAPI_Windows.h

```
#include "MyPlatformSpecificAPI.h"
class MyPlatformSpecificAPI_WIN64 : public MyPlatformSpecificAPI
{
public:
    virtual uint8_t myPlatformSpecificFoo(uint32_t bar) override;
    static MyPlatformSpecificAPI_WIN64 s_API;
};
```

> MyPlatformSpecificAPI_Windows.cpp

```
uint8_t MyPlatformSpecificAPI_WIN64::myPlatformSpecificFoo(uint32_t bar)
{
    //Perform windows specific calculations
    return 42; //because 42 is always the answer
}

MyPlatformSpecificAPI* MyPlatformSpecificAPI::getPlatformSpecificAPI()
{
    return &MyPlatformSpecificAPI_WIN64::s_API;
}
```

> MyPlatformSpecificAPI_Xbox.h

```
#include "MyPlatformSpecificAPI.h"
class MyPlatformSpecificAPI_Xbox : public MyPlatformSpecificAPI
{
public:
    virtual uint8_t myPlatformSpecificFoo(uint32_t bar) override;
    static MyPlatformSpecificAPI_Xbox s_API;
}
```

> MyPlatformSpecificAPI_Xbox.cpp

```
uint8_t MyPlatformSpecificAPI_Xbox::myPlatformSpecificFoo(uint32_t bar)
{
    //Perform Xbox specific calculations
    return 84;
};

MyPlatformSpecificAPI* MyPlatformSpecificAPI::getPlatformSpecificAPI()
{
    return &MyPlatformSpecificAPI_Xbox::s_API;
}
```